# ..."only if so are"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, usage

Many times I have seen constructions like

"Children are calm if so are their parents".

see, for example. https://www.google.ru/search?q=theorem+%22if+and+only+if+so+are+%22&newwindow=1&dcr=0&ei=BD4VWs2CFMaS6ATEtpmgBg&start=0&sa=N&biw=939&bih=321 However, I have failed to find a single instance of the construction

"Children are calm *only* if so are their parents".

Is the latter ungrammatical?

Comment: I find both sentences very odd and barely acceptable; but if the first is, then the second is.

Comment: Thanks. Would you find them equally inacceptable in academic writing?

Comment: Yes. I think the main problem is interference from the idiom "if so", which causes me to misparse them. But I'm also dubious about a V2 clause as the antecedent of an "if" (especially one where the antecedent follows the consequent).

Comment: @ColinFine -  Would "...(only) provided that so are their parents" make it more acceptable?

Comment: I don't see how it's possible for you to say you've seen constructions like this *many times*. Even with ***so*** in its "natural" position, and without the clumsy inversion *(Children are calm **if their parents are so**)*, it's somewhat ungainly. Most native speakers would simply discard the unnecessary word ***so*** in contexts like *They will be calm **if you are***.

Comment: But I did see them many times! take a look, for example, at  [this search on google.ru](https://www.google.ru/search?newwindow=1&dcr=0&biw=939&bih=321&ei=cDEUWtepKKKH6ATSy6TQBg&q=theorem+%22if+and+only+if+so+are+%22&oq=theorem+%22if+and+only+if+so+are+%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20125.33632.0.35433.12.12.0.0.0.0.57.550.12.12.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.i8OthikPxjU)

Comment: The first two pages of hits for that are **all** instances of the (solely mathematical) connector _if and only if_. I didn't read further. This is an entirely different case from what you are asking about.

Comment: So your search was for the terms `theorem "if and only if so are "` Why would you drop the "if and (only)" part of the phrase you searched for? Why would you qualify it with "theorem" and then change the context to "children"? If you saw this phrase in a technical context, it's OK to ask if it can be used in a non-technical context, but it is important to explain that when you ask your question instead of just saying "I've seen this many times".

Comment: It just didn't occur to me that "if and only if XYZ" is so different grammatically from "if  XYZ"

Comment: Actual examples you found need to be added to your question.

Comment: Done (a link is added)

Comment: The only place the phrase "Children are calm if so are their parents" is found on Google is on this page - so I don't see how you can say you have seen this construction many times. Is your question about general English text or about language used in mathematical text (as suggested by the search link you added)? If the latter, then please edit the question to reflect what you are actually asking.

Comment: Actually it was about both  general *and* mathematical English texts. Also initially  it was not about whether "if so are" is legitimate, but rather about the difference in frequency  between "if so are" and " only if so are"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with FumbleFingers that, if you have seen these kind of sentences "many times", the sentences were not written by native speakers. If you look through your linked examples, first, all are mathematical publications, and second, many seem to be written by academics for whom English is their second language (eg, "Topological Theory of Graphs" Yanpei Liu, Beijing Jiaotong University, Beijing, China.)

While it is *possible* to invert the usual word order in this way, it's awkward and unnatural and serves no useful purpose.  In specialized fields like mathematics you might see many such phrases that mirror a certain *logical* train of thought, but that does not mean you can use the same structure in ordinary conversation.  For example:

> The circuit is engaged **if and only if, so are** both logic gates.

This certainly makes sense to an academic, but a native speaker would be more likely to say:

> The circuit is engaged if and only if both logic gates **are engaged**.

To use your example:

> Children are well behaved **if and only if** their parents **are also** well-behaved.

Or, more succinctly:

> Unruly children **are due to** unruly parents.

Answer (score 1):

Both of these phrases are unnatural and not something a native speaker would say.

Instead of: "Children are calm if so are their parents."

We would say: "Children are calm if their parents are."